# Keeping passwords entered on command-line in shell script out of bash history

Tags: bash, shell, security, passwords, password-protection

I have a script that automates the creation of user accounts for SFTP.  The script relies on echo to echo the password into chpasswd ala:

```
echo <username>:<the password> | sudo chpasswd
```

...and openssl to check the resulting crypted password to ensure it's properly set:

```
openssl passwd -1 -salt <salt> <the password>
```

Since the script is printing the password directly on the command line, I'm concerned about this showing up in bash history, and/or other insecure areas.

I've considered appending HISTIGNORE:

```
HISTIGNORE="echo" echo <username>:<the password> | sudo chpasswd
```

Will this reliably keep the password out of history?

Comment: How are you calling the script? Commands in a script shouldn't end up in your history at all...

Comment: Executed via ruby, ruby script_name.rb.  Wasn't aware of that, I assumed they would end up in the history of the user that was executing the script, since the script interpreter is creating a new shell to execute each command

Comment: `ruby script_name.rb` will end up in the history, any commands contained within certainly won't.

Comment: Try `echo $(read) | sudo chpasswd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands *within* a script will not end up in your history. Only commands typed at the prompt.

Thus if your call your script with `ruby script.rb` and your ruby script executes a number of shell commands, these won't end up in the history, only the call to `ruby script.rb` will.

From my understanding `history` a standard bash function, and by doing some simple commands via `irb` we can see that bash is not the shell that's called by ruby, and none of the history variables or commands are present:

```
irb(main):002:0> puts `echo $0`
sh
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> puts `echo $HISTFILE`

=> nil
irb(main):004:0> puts `history`
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - history
        from (irb):4:in ``'
        from (irb):4
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):005:0>
```

The only time I've known the issue you describe to be a problem is when executing commands using `expect`. In this case, commands are typed directly to the terminal and do end up in the history. A neat trick to remove these commands is to use `history -c` which would clear any entries made in that session.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the [HISTCONTROL](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-HISTCONTROL) variable, you can prevent commands from being stored in history by prepending the command with whitespace:

```
$ echo $HISTCONTROL

$ echo my password is foo
my password is foo
$  echo my password is bar
my password is bar
$ history | tail -3
  497  echo my password is foo
  498   echo my password is bar
  499  history | tail -3
```

```
$ HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
$ echo my password is foo
my password is foo
$   echo my password is bar
my password is bar
$ history | tail -4
  499  history | tail -3
  500  HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
  501  echo my password is foo
  502  history | tail -4
```

In the 2nd example, the command prefixed with spaces don't show up in history.

---

You can use `history -d number` to delete entries from history.

Comment: Thanks.  Due to the script running on a variety of servers, I won't have direct control over HISTCONTROL, and need to set it per executing of the command, which is why I went with HISTIGNORE